# ScrollView can't scroll in an Android app

Tags: android

I use ScrollView as the root, then added LinearLayout, I tried several times, it just can't scroll at all, I tried to change android:layout_height="match_parent" in ScrollView to wrap_content and used LinearLayout as the root, then added ScrollView, then put LinearLayout in ScrollView, but it still can't scroll, I don't know what's the problem, ScrollView is working in my other app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/intro_background"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".IntroActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_app_name_intro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_title_text_marginTop"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/intro_screen_title_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_image_marginTop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_task_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lets_get_started_text_marginTop"
        android:text="@string/let_s_get_started_text"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/lets_get_started_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/intro_text_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_text_marginTop"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/intro_text_marginStartEnd"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/intro_text_line_spacing_extra"
        android:text="@string/intro_text_description"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/intro_text_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in_intro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_sign_in_btn_marginTop"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button_rounded"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up_intro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_sign_up_btn_marginTop"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
        android:background="@drawable/white_border_shape_button_rounded"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I tried to put ScrollView within LinearLayout, which is not working. The code is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/intro_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".IntroActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_app_name_intro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_title_text_marginTop"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/intro_screen_title_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_image_marginTop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_task_image" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lets_get_started_text_marginTop"
                android:text="@string/let_s_get_started_text"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/lets_get_started_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/intro_text_marginStartEnd"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_text_marginTop"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/intro_text_marginStartEnd"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/intro_text_line_spacing_extra"
                android:text="@string/intro_text_description"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/intro_text_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in_intro"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_sign_in_btn_marginTop"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_button_rounded"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
                android:text="@string/sign_in"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up_intro"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_sign_up_btn_marginTop"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
                android:background="@drawable/white_border_shape_button_rounded"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
                android:text="@string/sign_up"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The prolem is not how I use ScrollView, the problem is `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

showed a warning, Attribute android:foreground has no effect on API levels lower than 23 (current min is 21), then I clicked override Resource in layout-v23, so Android Studio genrated an xml file, activity_intro.xml (v23), I needed to change both of activity_intro.xml (v23) and activity_intro.xml, then it works.

Comment: i think your scroll view is correct but issue in linear layout childs.

Comment: What issue? I can't see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For ScrollView to scroll the contents within the content should be larger than the height of ScrollView. You are correct in keeping the ScrollView as match_parent but I do not think a few Buttons or TextViews are enough to make it scroll. For Testing you can try to make height of one of the views very large like 2000dp and see if it scrolls.

Comment: When I tested it on an emulator, it showed everything since it didn't need to scroll, but when I tested on my real phone, the last button only showed half of it, and can't scroll.